# Transfer Data Row from Table to the bottom of another Table on different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to transfer a row of data from one table to a new row at the bottom of another table when a date is entered into the cell(Column "AD").

When I try, data is transferred to the row under the last row of the table.

```vb
Sub TRANSFER_DATA()

For Each Cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AD2:AD1000")
    If Cell.Value > 0 Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Cut

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: *at the bottom*, *row UNDERNEATH* Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: And it's not clear what is *table* for you. Is it a `Range` or `ListObject`?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question you can try this code:
Execute the macro when you have the sheet1 active

```
Sub TRANSFER_DATA()
Dim lastrow, i As Long
Dim ADCell as Integer

ADCell=30 ' control the column AD
'control how many data there are in column A. If you want count how many rows
'with ColumnAD change 1 in 30 (lastrow = Cells(rows.count,30).End(xlUp).Row)
lastrow = Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, ADCell) > 0 Then
        rows(i & ":" & i).Select
        Selection.Cut Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I tried the code and works.

> UPDATED THE POST AFTER YOUR COMMENT

```
Sub TRANSFER_DATA()
Dim lastrow, i, ls As Long
Dim ADCell as Integer

ADCell=30 ' control the column AD
'control how many data there are in column A. If you want count how many rows
'with ColumnAD change 1 in 30 (lastrow = Cells(rows.count,30).End(xlUp).Row)
lastrow = Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, ADCell) > 0 Then
        rows(i & ":" & i).Select
        Selection.Cut Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next i
With Sheets("sheet2")

  ls = .Cells(.rows.count, ADCell).End(xlUp).Row
  .ListObjects("TableName").Resize Range("$A$1:$AD$" & ls)

End With

End Sub
```

the updated code have another variable, ls. This variable has the number of not empty rows of sheet2. ListObjects.("name of your table") insert the new data (rows) into the table.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help, however this code is causing the same problem of moving the row from table 1 to the row underneath the last row of table 2.  I am pretty sure the code has to reference the table using List Object references or possibly a PasteSpecial command, but I am not familiar with using them.

Comment: can you explain me if you want the data from last empty row or no...? Why i don't understand well what you want...

Comment: Yes I want the data in the last empty row of the table, which requires a new row of the table to be created and the data pasted into that new row.  That is where I am having trouble.  Everything I try pastes the data on the row below the entire table instead of pasting it to a row in the table... So for instance if my table row ends on row 80, I want the table to create a row in row 81 and paste the information in that row so it is part of the table.  I apologize if I am not as clear as I need to be, I am new to VBA and am teaching myself.  Thank you for your assistance with this!

Comment: @Dan4ya i have updated the post... Keep me updated...so i have understood your problem... :)